# Retargeting armature to human when large offsets in some bones to cater for a custom character's anatomy

Tags: animation, armature, unreal-engine

**Intro:**

This question is slightly weighted on the Unreal Engine side, but perhaps I can gather a better understanding from 3D animation artists, thus the question has landed here.

**Context:**

Unreal Engine (A 3d game engine) has an armature. It looks like this:

[image]

I have copied this armature in the hopes of being able to retarget animations I purchase from their marketplace and so have changed the transformations of the Unreal Engine armature to best match my character. You can see the end result I have come up with that matches what I'd assume my character's skeleton might look like:

[image]

My character is a bit frustrating because of the offset of `d` causing problems in retargeting.

[image]

**Question:**

- When retargeting, is there a limit to how much retargeting can do? You can see that my character's offset of `d` means any weighting I give my character is warped dramatically by the offset from the original unreal engine armature, here's an example of what I see:

[image]

- What can I expect to achieve with retargeting? Do I need to change my character If I want to be able to retarget animations from Unreal Engine assets. (perhaps redesigning to better match a human's proportions?)
- Does anyone have an example of a more complex retargeting and perhaps a list of lessons learned that might help me to get this to work correctly.

**What I've tried already:**

- Originally, I made the character's arms sit in the middle of the body (`d = 0`), but then that made the arms go through the front of the mesh when an animation asset perhaps grabbed forward onto a ledge. The retargeting and weighting was an issue to get right.
- I've tried removing weighting for the clavicle but then there doesn't appear to be any good way of weighting the upper arms to get those offsets just right.
- I've tried changing the positions of the clavicle along the length of `d`, to see if I can get a good compromise between stretching/warping and yet close enough to the animation to not notice the flaws.
- I've tried different translation retargeting options (It's a bit Unreal Engine-y, but perhaps it makes sense to show it here - note the root and pelvis Animation/Animation Scaled):

[image]

Unreal Engine documentation for retargeting: https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/AnimatingObjects/SkeletalMeshAnimation/AnimationRetargeting/index.html?utm_source=editor&utm_medium=docs&utm_campaign=rich_tooltips#howdoesretargetingwork?

**Last thought:**

I think, what I need, is a bunch of in-the-know people to tell me "yes, this is possible, we did this before but it was a bit fiddly" or "no, you're an idiot. of course you can't re-use such a non-matching skeleton, good luck making all the animations yourself, n00b". Perhaps someone to reassure me that I "just need to spend more time with weighting and bone positions", or to say "it's nothing to do with bone positions, only weighting".. etc